# Why is this Firebase IDBIndex error happening on Smart TV web app, and are there workarounds?

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics, wpe

**Background & Context**

We are building HTML free to play games for a widely distributed set top box, to be played on users' TVs.
The box itself runs a WebKit (WPE) browser, running on a modified version of [RDK](https://rdkcentral.com/).
The box can only communicate with IPv6 compatible servers, and all third party endpoints must be white-listed.

We want to track data about user behavior in our game, and store it in a database our data analyst can query to create detailed analyses.
The intention is to use this data to improve game tuning, game design, and creative design to improve user experience and optimize retention.

The solution we devised:
Log events to Firebase Analytics & link that service to BigQuery for complex querying.

**- The Issue -**

First issue - When we try to load scripts from the html file of our page (according to [this guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup)) everything works fine when we test in Google Chrome... On the Smart TV Box however, the scripts are loaded and run out of order. For some reason, the browser on the box does not load scripts in the order they are defined on the page, even when the defer property is added to the html script elements. This was causing issues where the script file for the Firebase Analytics package was getting initialized before the base Firebase/app package was finished loading. We also saw a mysterious error about "IDBIndex" but thought it was related to the script load order issue...

We bundled up the [firebase npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase) into its own minified script file using webpack, with a small bit of logic to initialize it with our app's properties. The intention is to load the base package and the analytics and performance monitoring packages all at once, together, and initialize them in the correct order. This gets loaded by our html file separately from our game logic script file, and the rest of our game logic will wait on the "DOMContentLoaded" event before running.

Real Issue Arises - Now, the solution above still runs perfectly in Google Chrome, but when we test on the Smart TV hardware, we still get the following error from the IDB package used by the firebase analytics script:

[Here's the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXaz1.png)

We think this is because of a browser feature missing from the one running on the box, but it's also possible that it has to do with the box's hardware. The box does not provide any form of local persistent storage. All persistent data must be saved in a "cloud cookie" which is just a cookie saved to the Smart TV users' account and synced with the Smart TV platform's servers. This gets loaded from their servers before our app initializes every time it is launched.

I worked with the platform's developer support team, and all they were able to say was this:

> "It looks like the app is trying to use Index DB which is disabled on
> devices, I suggest trying to exclude firedatabase from the firebase
> you are trying to use. this should make it work."

As far as I'm aware, this is not something I have the ability to modify in Firebase's web app plugin config. Am I mistaken?

Please let me know what other info I can provide. Thank you so much in advance for your help!